# SlideDeck 2, make back-end visible for admins only

Tags: menus, customization, admin

I'd like to make the back-end of the [SlideDeck 2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slidedeck2/) plugin visible for admin users only.
Also, I'd like to remove that "Insert SlideDeck" button from the editor.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in your `functions.php`:

```
if (is_admin() && ! current_user_can('install_plugins')) {
    add_action('admin_init', 'remove_slidedeck_menu_page');
    add_action('admin_footer', 'remove_slidedeck_media_button');
}

// remove the menu page
function remove_slidedeck_menu_page() {
    remove_menu_page('slidedeck2-lite.php');
}

// remove the button
function remove_slidedeck_media_button() {
    echo <<<JQUERY
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#add_slidedeck').remove();
});
</script>
JQUERY;
}
```

**Note**: I **did** test this. If something doesn't work for you, please report back. If it does, please come back as well (and vote up/accept). ;)

**// EDIT**: the menu page is now working.

**// EDIT 2**: the button as well.